# How to load custom plugins in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, load, instantiation

I'm writing a poll plugin for a website based on CakePHP. The plugin works good if I access it from its own URL (eg. `myapp.com/plugin/controller`) but I need to call it from different pages. I would like to include it as a widget in every page.

I'm looking for a method like `$myplugin->renderPoll($pollId);` but I really didn't find any information about how to instantiate the Polls class. I tried with `App::import` and `ClassRegistry::init` with no luck.

Any suggestion ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create some sort of `Helper` to create poll cross views? I would suggest creating a `Helper` for that particular class. Simply create a helper in `plugins/plugin_name/views/helpers/foo.php`, and in each controller (or in `app_controller.php`) that you need it, include the helpers as `$helpers = array("PluginName.Foo");` and inside your view, you should be able to use the methods defined in `foo.php` by calling `$foo->renderPoll($pollId)`.

```
//app/plugins/plugin_name/views/helpers/foo.php
class FooHelper extends AppHelper {
    var $name = "Foo";

    function renderPoll($id=0) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Elements! They're small blocks of presentation code that need to be repeated from page to page, sometimes in different places in the layout.

Check this link out: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

I guess this link explains everything you need.